# Webpack HotModuleReplacement css

Tags: javascript, sass, webpack

I am trying to use webpack as a replacement for gulp and livereload workflow. I have set up HotModuleReplacement Plugin and it works correctly for JS files but I can't get it to work with SCSS files. It is compiling the SCSS to CSS properly but I have to manually refresh the browser each time to get the style changes to show. I am thinking it maybe a mistake in how I have the config set up or something like that.

I have this server.js file that is running things:

```
var webpack = require('webpack');
var WebpackDevServer = require('webpack-dev-server');
var config = require('./webpack.config');

new WebpackDevServer(webpack(config), {
    publicPath: config.output.publicPath,
    hot: true,
    historyApiFallback: true,
    noInfo: true,   
    stats: { colors: true }
}).listen(3000, 'localhost', function (err, result) {
    if (err) {
    console.log(err);
    }

    console.log('Listening at localhost:3000');
});
```

and this webpack.config.js

```
var path = require('path');
var webpack = require('webpack');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');

var cssLoaders = ['css-loader'];
var jsLoaders = ['react-hot', 'babel'];
var scssLoaders = cssLoaders.slice(0);
scssLoaders.push('sass-loader?includePaths[]=' + path.resolve(__dirname, './styles'));

module.exports = {

  devtool: 'sourcemap',
  entry: [
    'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000',
    'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
    './scripts/index'
  ],
  output: {
    path: path.join(__dirname, './build'),
    filename: 'bundle.js',
    publicPath: '/build/'
  },
  plugins: [
    new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin(),
    new webpack.NoErrorsPlugin(),
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css')
  ],
  resolve: {
    extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx', '.scss']
  },
  module: {
    loaders: [
      { test: /\.js?$/, loaders: jsLoaders, include: path.join(__dirname, 'scripts'), exclude: /node_modules/},
      { test: /\.css$/ ,loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', cssLoaders.join('!')) },
      { test: /\.js$/, loader: "eslint-loader", exclude: /node_modules/ },
      { test: /\.scss$/, loader: ExtractTextPlugin.extract('style-loader', scssLoaders.join('!')) }
    ]
  }
};
```

In one of my js files I just have a call to the SCSS file like this:

```
require('../styles/app');
```

I have looked into the docs for this and there are some instructions that suggest that you need to manually opt in for each module but I am not sure why that is, where to add that code etc
What I am trying to do seems like a pretty straight forward use case so is this supported or will I still also have to use gulp and live reload just for styles?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately the `extract-text-webpack-plugin`, which is extracting all your styles to a CSS file, doesn't work well with hot-reloading (see https://github.com/webpack/extract-text-webpack-plugin/issues/30).

This hacky bit of JavaScript will reload all stylesheets any time it detects *any* hot reload event happening.  It can get annoying, though, and works better on Firefox than on Chrome - Chrome seems to delay applying the new stylesheet until you focus the browser tab.

```
if (module.hot) {
    $(window).on("message onmessage", function(event) {
        if (typeof event.originalEvent.data === "string" && event.originalEvent.data.indexOf("webpackHotUpdate") === 0) {
            console.log("Reloading style sheets...");
            document.styleSheets.forEach(function (sheet) {
                if ((sheet.href || "").indexOf('localhost') !== -1) {
                    sheet.ownerNode.href = sheet.href;
                }
            });
        }
    });
}
```

There may be some way to hook further into the guts of the hot reloading code, but I haven't looked into it.

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, `extract-text-webpack-plugin` is not working properly with hot replacement, unfortunately :( But there's one more option how to solve this issue while development. That's **disable** property in extract plugin settings.

Modify a bit your config as described below:

```
plugins: [
    new ExtractTextPlugin('styles.css', {disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'})
]
```

That will disable usage of `ExtractTextPlugin` while development (I mean if you run it anyhow but `NODE_ENV=production webpack`, or any other rule you prefer) and bundle your styles within js.

Also mind importing your style file in the entry point. Hope that works. Cheers ;)

---

PS. Also you can avoid combining your entry point with `'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:3000', 'webpack/hot/only-dev-server'` and adding `new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()` to plugins manually just by running webpack dev server with additional params

```
webpack-dev-server --inline --hot
```

`inline` stands for `webpack-dev-server/client` and `--hot` for `webpack-dev-server/client`